# Hanoi Tower(Towers of Hanoi)

Tags: prolog, towers-of-hanoi

I'm trying to do the Towers of Hanoi problem,  what I have tried so far:

```
move(1,[H|T],B,C,A1,B1,C) :-  
  A1 = T,
  B1 = [H|B].
move(N,A,B,C,A1,B1,C) :- 
N>1, 
M is N-1, 
move(M,[H|T],C,B,A1,B1,C), 
move(1,[H|T],B,_,A1,B1,C), 
move(M,C,B,[H|T],A1,B1,C).
```

but this code does not work, I need get the result is looks like this:

```
?-move(3,[1,2,3],[],[],A1,B1,C).
  and the results:
  A1=[].
  B1=[1,2,3]
  C=[].
```

can someone help me fix my code up and can get the result like that? This is very important for me, I really need help.
this is what i did but with some problems:

```
move(N,[H|T],[],[],A1,B1,C) :-
      N > 1,
      M is N - 1,   
      move(N,[H|M],[H|_],[],A1,B1,C),
      move(M,[_|M],[H|_],[H|_],A1,B1,C),
      move(M,[_|M],[],[H|T],A1,B1,C),
      move(M,[],[_|T],[H|T],A1,B1,C),
      move(M,[H|_],[_|T],[H|T],A1,B1,C),
      move(M,[H|_],[_|T],[],A1,B1,C),
      move(M,[],[H|T],[],A1,B1,C).
      move(N,[H|T],[],[]) :- write(A1), nl,
                             write(B1), nl,
                             write(C).
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the instruction by instruction of solving towers of Hanoi problem.

```
   move(1,X,Y,_) :-  
        write('Move top disk from '), 
        write(X), 
        write(' to '), 
        write(Y), 
        nl. 
    move(N,X,Y,Z) :- 
        N>1, 
        M is N-1, 
        move(M,X,Z,Y), 
        move(1,X,Y,_), 
        move(M,Z,Y,X).
```

Attack the problem in such a way: In the instruction by instruction solution we don't change the contents of X,Y or Z. But in your problem, you will eventually change the contents of them.

UPDATE:
Since it is declared that this is not a homework question, here is the full answer:

```
towersOfHanoi(N,A,B,C,A4,B4,C4) :- move(N,A,B,C,A4,B4,C4),!.

move(1,[H|T],B,C,A1,B1,C1) :-  A1 = T,
                               B1 = [H|B],
                               C1 = C.
move(N,A,B,C,A4,B4,C4) :-   N>1, 
                            M is N-1, 
                            move(M,A,C,B,A1,C1,B1), 
                            move(1,A1,B1,C1,A2,B2,C2), 
                            move(M,C2,B2,A2,C4,B4,A4).
```

Comment: sorry, i tag it wrong, this is not homework, is one question of past exam. if you can give me full answers, i have exam in next week. sorry about that

Comment: i thouht i can use my way, but i dont know where is wrong, because i just following the steps to write the code

Comment: The wrong point of you is not changing the contents of A,B,C via A1,B1,C1. If you are listing what to do, it is OK. But if you implement the solver like me, you need to change to contents of the lists.

Comment: true, but my way is too complete. the another question is following this question in above.

Comment: @user1400451 what does that mean "too complete"? By the way, I don't care about another question because you gave me only and only this one.

Comment: @user1400451 why do you edit my post irrelevantly? If you have another question ask separately or add to the original question body.